# How do I represent a 24-hour clock with the STL?

Tags: c++, stl, std, c++-chrono

I'm looking for a solution from the STL, for dealing with "time of day". I am working on a simple unit test exercise, with behavior depending on whether current time is in the morning, evening or night.

For a first iteration I used a humble integer as a stand-in for some "time object":

```
using TimeOfDay = int;
constexpr bool isBetween(TimeOfDay in, TimeOfDay min, TimeOfDay max) noexcept {
  return in >= min && in <= max; 
}
constexpr bool isMorning(TimeOfDay in) noexcept { 
  return isBetween(in, 6, 12); }
constexpr bool isEvening(TimeOfDay in) noexcept {
  return isBetween(in, 18, 22);
}
constexpr bool isNight(TimeOfDay in) noexcept {
  return isBetween(in, 22, 24) || isBetween(in, 0, 6);
}

constexpr string_view getGreetingFor(TimeOfDay time) noexcept {
  if (isMorning(time)) {
    return "Good morning "sv;
  }
  if (isEvening(time)) {
    return "Good evening "sv;
  }
  if (isNight(time)) {
    return "Good night "sv;
  }
  return "Hello "sv;
}
```

This works but has a couple of smells:

- the `int` simply isn't the right type to represent a 24 hour clock
- `isNight()` requires an unnecessarily complicated comparison, due to wrapping (22-06)
- ideally I would like to be able actually use the system clock for some of my tests.
- `std::chrono::system_clock::now()` returns a `std::chrono::time_point`, so my ideal type should probably be something that can be compared to a `time_point`, or easily constructed from a `time_point`.

Any pointers would be very appreciated!

(I am working in Visual Studio with C++Latest (preview of the C++ working draft, so roughly C++23))

Comment: Based on the comparison logics you have right now, your `TimeOfDay` is actually just `Hour`. `TimeOfDay` should either be an object that has hour, minute, and second in it, or it should be the total seconds it has been for the day *(hr\*3600 + min\*60 + sec)*

Comment: Check this library https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date AFAIK it should become part of C++ standard.

Comment: Using system clock for tests is a terrible idea. You want reproducibility.

Comment: *"`isNight()` requires an unnecessarily complicated comparison, due to wrapping (22-06)"* You might reverse the comparison: `return not isBetween(in, 7, 21);`.

Comment: @Jarod42; That's a beautiful fix, obvious in hindsight. Thanks for the suggestion, and for editing the post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to start with the assumption that you're looking for the *local* time of day.  `chrono::system_clock` represents UTC.  So I recommend a helper function that takes `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` and returns a `std::chrono::system_clock::duration` which represents the time elapsed since the most recent local midnight:

```
using TimeOfDay = std::chrono::system_clock::duration;

TimeOfDay
get_local_time_of_day(std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp) noexcept
{
  using namespace std::chrono;
  auto time = current_zone()->to_local(tp);
  return time - floor<days>(time);
}
```

`chrono::current_zone()` returns a pointer to the `chrono::time_zone` that your computer is currently set to.  This is used to convert the `system_clock::time_point` to a *local* `time_point`.  This local `time_point` is a `chrono::time_point` but with a different clock that means "local time".

The expression `floor<days>(time)` truncates the `time_point` to precision `days`, which effectively gives you a pointer to the most recently passed local midnight.  Subtracting that from `time` gives you a `chrono::duration` since the local midnight.  This `duration` will have the same precision as `tp`.

This function can not be made `constexpr` because the rules for transforming UTC to local time is in the hands of your politicians and is subject to change (in many countries twice a year!).

Now you can write `isMorning` (et al) like this:

```
bool isMorning(std::chrono::system_clock::time_point in) noexcept { 
  using namespace std::literals;
  return isBetween(get_local_time_of_day(in), 6h, 12h); }
```

And call it like this:

```
if (isMorning(system_clock::now())) ...
```

Your logic for `isNight` looks fine to me.  And your code for `isBetween` can stay like it is (picking up the new definition of `TimeOfDay`).

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about time within a day, detached from a date, use a [`std::chrono::duration`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration). For integer hours, there is the alias `std::chrono::hours`.

See also [`std::chrono::hh_mm_ss`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/hh_mm_ss)

Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;

int main()
{
    auto now = system_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
    auto today = duration_cast<days>(now);
    hh_mm_ss time { now - today };
    std::cout << time.hours() << time.minutes() << time.seconds();
}
```

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27854aeb2443a672)

Comment: Note `floor` should be preferred over `duration_cast` to get proper result prior to epoch.

Comment: Not sure that the modulus by day is correct: Between [daylight saving time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) and even [leap second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second).

Answer (score 0):

The "time of day" should be stored in a `std::chrono::duration`. To detach only the h/m/s information of any `duration`, you can do:

```cpp
auto time_info = my_duration - std::chrono::round<std::chrono::days>(my_duration);
```

Similarly, you can detach the h/m/s information of a `time_point` with the same interface:

```cpp
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto time_info = now - std::chrono::round<std::chrono::days>(now);
```

Then you can use the helper class `hh_mm_ss` to examine the information:

```cpp
auto hms = std::chrono::hh_mm_ss{ time_info };
std::cout << hms.hours() << hms.minutes() << hms.seconds();
```

---

To check if a `duration` is between two other time, you can do:

```cpp
using TimeOfDay = std::chrono::seconds;

constexpr bool isBetween(TimeOfDay in, TimeOfDay min, TimeOfDay max) noexcept {
    return in >= min && in <= max; 
}

constexpr bool isMorning(TimeOfDay in) noexcept { 
    return isBetween(in, std::chrono::hours{6}, std::chrono::hours{12}); 
}
```

You can also enable the literals by `using namespace std::chrono_literals` or `using namespace std::literals`:

```cpp
constexpr bool isMorning(TimeOfDay in) noexcept { 
    return isBetween(in, 6h, 12h); 
}
```

---

For the wrapping in `isEvening`, you can potentially do something like: `isBetween(in + 12h - days{1}, 10h, 18h)`, but I think what you have right now have a much cleaner and easier to follow logic.

---

And this can be easily turned back to a `time_point` if needed:

```cpp
auto today = std::chrono::round<std::chrono::days>(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
auto now = today + time_info;
```